# Node.js Database Query

Tags: javascript, node.js

**EDIT**
My question has changed slightly so I'm updating my code and revising my question. Everything seems to be working except I'm not seeing my JSON returned in my browser.

Here is my current code:

```
'use strict';
var util = require('util');
var http = require('http');
var sql = require("mssql");
var express = require('express')
var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;

var membershipNumber;
var results;
var queryString;

var app = express();

function getParams() {
    app.get('/:number', function (req, res) {
        console.log("\nPARAMS:");
        console.log(req.params.number);

        membershipNumber = req.params.number;
        queryString = util.format('SELECT major_key, status, paid_thru FROM name WHERE major_key = \'%s\' and member_record = 1', membershipNumber);
        console.log("\nQUERY:");
        console.log(queryString);

        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        // res.end(queryDatabase(queryString));
        res.send(queryDatabase(queryString));
    });
    app.listen(port);
}

function queryDatabase(query) {
    var config = {
        server: 'testserver',
        database: 'test_db',
        user: 'sa',
        password: 'password',
        port: 1433
    };

    var connection = new sql.Connection(config);

    connection.connect().then(function () {
        var req = new sql.Request(connection);
        req.query(query).then(function (recordset) {
            results = recordset;
            console.log("\nRESULTS:");
            console.log(results);
            connection.close();

            //Convert results to JSON string
            var jsonString = JSON.stringify(results);
            console.log("\njsonString:");
            console.log(jsonString);

            return jsonString;

        })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err);
                connection.close();
            });
    })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
}

getParams();
```

And here is what my console.log statements print in the console"

```
PARAMS:
0001354648

QUERY:
SELECT major_key, status, paid_thru FROM name WHERE major_key = '0001354648' and member_record = 1

RESULTS:
[ { major_key: '0001354648',
    status: 'SN',
    paid_thru: 2016-10-31T00:00:00.000Z } ]

jsonString:
[{"major_key":"0001354648","status":"SN","paid_thru":"2016-10-31T00:00:00.000Z"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two `app.listen()` calls: one in `appFunction()` and another in `getParams()`. You should only call `app.listen()` once and remove the one in `appFunction()` since `getParams()` seems to be the function you are calling on initialization.

If you really need your code to be structured that way, try this:

```
function queryDatabase(query) {
  var config = {
    server: 'dbserver',
    database: 'test_db',
    user: 'sa',
    password: 'password',
    port: 1433
  };

  var connection = new sql.Connection(config);

  connection.connect().then(function() {
      var req = new sql.Request(connection);
      req.query(query).then(function(recordset) {
          results = recordset;
          console.log("\nRESULTS:");
          console.log(results);
          connection.close();

          //Convert results to JSON string
          jsonString = JSON.stringify(results);
          console.log("\nJSON:");
          console.log(jsonString);

          appFunction(jsonString);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          console.log(err);
          connection.close();
        });
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
}

app.get('/:number', function(req, res) {
  console.log("\nPARAMS:");
  console.log(req.params.number);

  membershipNumber = req.params.number;
  queryString = util.format('SELECT major_key, status, paid_thru FROM name WHERE major_key = \'%s\' and member_record = 1', membershipNumber);
  console.log("\nQUERY:");
  console.log(queryString);

  res.end(queryDatabase(queryString));
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.send(jsonString);
});

app.listen(port);
```

Note that this will only work with one request at a time.

I'd highly suggest to return the output of your `queryDatabase()` function back to the user when the REST call is made; In this case, your '/:number' route would return the JSON string you want to recieve. in your app that would RESTfully interface with this, you'd see something along the lines of:

```
GET http://<your-ip>:<your-port>/3
RESPONSE: { some JSON }
```

At this point you would not need the '/' route.

Comment: i understand that and I mentioned that in my question. The problem with removing the one in appFunction() is that when I take it out, I don't get the JSON string.

Comment: sorry about that. I made an edit that suggests a way to get your JSON string (see the bottom of the post)

Comment: tl;dr: return the JSON string in the '/:number' route instead of using another route to return it.

Comment: How could I implement your suggestion with just using the '/:number' route?

Comment: have the `queryDatabase` function `return jsonString;`. this will send the JSON back to the user as part of the response for calling the `/:number` route.

Comment: I added 'return jsonString;'  to it and don't get it back in the browser.

Comment: try changing `res.end` to `res.send`. this should actually send the JSON data back to the browser. If you want it to pretty print, you can use `JSON.stringify` to stringify the output: `res.send(JSON.stringify(func(), null, 3))`. Replace the 3 with the number of spaces that would be an indent, and func() with the query function();

Comment: Still get nothing in the browser and I'm already using JSON.stringify in queryDatabase().

Comment: Try adding this: `res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');` before the `res.send` line. Does your console log show that the JSON is actually being made i.e. the query is successful? It's really odd that you aren't getting a result.

Comment: I've added that as well and the console.log() in queryDatabase() prints 'jsonString'.

Comment: What does the console log and what does your browser say when you do this after your query in your queryFunction():
`jsonString = JSON.stringify(results);`
`console.log(jsonString);`
`return jsonString`

Comment: The browser doesn't say anything and the console.log() calls from my queryDatabase() function show: RESULTS:
[ { major_key: '0001354648',
    status: 'SN',
    paid_thru: 2016-10-31T00:00:00.000Z } ]

JSON:
[{"major_key":"0001354648","status":"SN","paid_thru":"2016-10-31T00:00:00.000Z"}]